# spatie/laravel-image-optimizer Not optimizing images in Laravel 10x, Not working

Tags: php, laravel, github, file-upload, laravel-10

I am using the spatie/laravel-image-optimizer package and i followed the documents from [github](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer).

step 1: `composer require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer`

step 2: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerServiceProvider"`

step 3: below is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Basic;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\Facades\ImageOptimizer;

class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImageForm(){
        return view('uploadImage');
    }

    public function uploadImage(Request $request){

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
            $imagePath = public_path('images/'.$imageName);
            
            ImageOptimizer::optimize($imagePath);

            return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully');
            
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('upload.image.form');
        }

    }
}
```

and now the issue is that image is uploading successfully but the image size is not optimizing as i have image of 7.9mb before uploading and after upload it's still the same size ??